# How to Change xCode App icons

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I want to change my App icon, so, I delete (move to trash) Icon.png and Icon@2x.png in the project navigator, in summary view I have added the new icons and they are added to my project, and I see them in the summary

[image]

But, when I install the app, the icon is the previous one. How can I clean the previous icon in order to install the new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes when building direct to the device it doesn't work first time.

I find I have to clean the project and delete the app from the device/simulator to get the new icon.

Answer (score 4):

Just **Clean** And **Build** And **Delete The app** from Simulator . it will work

Answer (score 4):

Just do this... This will solve your problem..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to reset the simulator.